# Import Queries from Access

Tags: vba, excel

I connect Access database to Excel by VBA, importing data from a single table,"Category" , to the worksheet. code below but, instead of table, can I import Query that already exists in the database?

It show "error" when I change the Table name to the Query name in line 15.

```
    'connection Declairation
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim data As ADODB.Recordset

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set data = New ADODB.Recordset
    ' end of connection Declairation
    conn.ConnectionString = ConstrAccess

    conn.Open
    On Error GoTo closeconnection
                With data
                    .ActiveConnection = conn 'specfied the connection
                    .Source = "Category" ' works only for Table Type
                    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
                    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
                    .Open
                End With
                On Error GoTo closerecordset


                Datasheet.Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset data
                On Error GoTo 0



closerecordset:
                data.Close
closeconnection:
    conn.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot recreate your issue. A named, stored query works on my end: Excel 2013, Win 10, MS ActiveX 6.1 Library reference. What is the error you receive?

Comment: You can try this - `Data` > `From Access` > select the Access file > if you don't see your query in the list, then you might have to change the query until it shows up in the list. For example `SELECT * FROM ([query name])`

Comment: @Parfait Sorry I missed the connectionString,<br> `Const ConstrAccess As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=(path of Database).accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"`

Comment: @Slai What a fool I am, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you change to Recordset and TableDef? You won't need to open the DataBase either that way; Add a Reference (tools->references) for Microsoft Office xx.x Access database engine Object Library

```
Sub test()
Dim BDAnalyzed As Database
Dim RecordTable As Recordset
Dim RecordTableDef As TableDef
Dim CounterTitles As Long
Const DesiredQuery = "Title For Query"
Const PathToDB = "C:..."
    Set BDAnalyzed = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(PathToDB)
    Set RecordTable = BDAnalyzed.OpenRecordset(DesiredQuery, dbOpenDynaset)
    Set RecordTableDef = BDAnalyzed.TableDefs(RecordTable)
    For CounterTitles = 0 To RecordTableDef.Fields.Count - 1
    MsgBox RecordTableDef.Fields(CounterTitles).Name
    Next CounterTitles
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.your code is more easy than mine, I'll try to learn from it.